# flutter code does not run when two ..functions are present

Tags: flutter, dart

i was wondering if there was an expert that could help me out.

I am following a video for building an app...

For some weird reason, I can only have 1 one the following functions:
..addListener.                <== line 27
OR
..addStatusListener.     <== line 29

If I comment out one and leave the other, the code works. If I don't comment out one of them, the code does not work. any idea what the issue is?

video I am following is:: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ck9L645ucrM&list=PLxefhmF0pcPlqR5FBT9_51HcIFLRvzci2&index=6
go to time=11:16

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MwIk.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We solved this in chat.  Turns out OP was writing

```
..addListener( .... );
..addStatusListener( .... )
```

which of course is broken syntax.  Removing the semicolon fixed it.